# assert that a double can fit into an int

Tags: c++, c++11, int, double, overflow

I am not very sure whether a `double` has a standardized representation or not thats why I wanted to ask, is there a good way to write an `assert` that makes sure that a value in a `double` is small enough to fit into an `int64_t`?

More specifically is the comparison between an `int64_t` and a `double` that might be out of the former's range well defined and guaranteed to be correct?

Comment: [relevant Dr Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/comparing-an-integer-with-a-floating-poi/240150323)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would work:

```
assert(std::numeric_limit<int64_t>::min() <= value
       && value <= std::numeric_limits<int64_t>:::max()
```

Comment: Is a comparison between a `double` that might be larger than an `int64_t` and an `int64_t` well defined?

Comment: @Curious I'd introduce `static_cast` additionally. It's actually all well defined.

Comment: But is it guaranteed that the cast between an `int64_t` and a `double` is not going to lose any precision, and subsequently lead to an incorrect result?

Comment: @Curious: if you additionally need to verify that the `double` holds an integer value, just also use `assert(int64_t(value) == value);`

Comment: Note: you generally want lowest() not min() when using limits - they're actually the same value for integral types (so the above code is correct), but for floats and doubles min() is a very small positive floating point value, and lowest() is the real minimum value...

Answer (score 0):

You can try by checking type limits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double val = static_cast<double>(LONG_MAX); // or LONG_MIN

    assert((static_cast<long int>(val) > LONG_MIN) && (static_cast<long int>(val) < LONG_MAX));
    cout << static_cast<long int>(val) << '\n';
}
```